# invalid column name 'a'

Tags: c#, mysql

I have a query that runs through and is supposed to extract a name and email address of a user if the code entered matches the one found in the table. The code is a primary key on another table and is a foreign key on the name and email table. However whenever I run the query it returns invalid column name 'a'.

```
// the variable course runs through a method to capture the 
// code from a textbox the user enters it in.
string sql = "select * from SI where Course= " + course;
SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(sql, connection.con);
SqlDataReader read = command.ExecuteReader();
if (read.Read())
{
    siname = read["Name"].ToString();
    siemail = read["Email"].ToString();
}
read.Close();
```

Comment: is your column course is nvarchar ?

Comment: This is one reason you should use parameters instead of concatenating values into your SQL.  The other is SQL injection attacks.

Answer (score 4):

Use parameters instead of string concatenation to avoid injection attacks - imaginge the value of `course` would be `'' GO DROP TABLE SI GO`.

Another thing is the use of the `using` statement. That will release unused connections and memory as soon as code runs out of scope.

```
string command= "select * from SI where Course = @course";
using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
{
    connection.Open();
    using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(command, connection))
    {
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@course", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = course;
        using (SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
        {                        
            if (read.Read())
            {
                siname = read["Name"].ToString();
                siemail = read["Email"].ToString();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Ben Chan beat me to it. Issue is likely not using the '' around the user input. I'll also suggest using parameters in your sql command as well, prevents SQL injection and makes it look better. Instead of

```
string sql = "select * from SI where Course= '" + course + "'";
```

You can just use:

```
string sql = "select * from SI where Course = @course";
```

Full code:

```
// the variable course runs through a method to capture the 
// code from a textbox the user enters it in.
string sql = "select * from SI where Course = @course";
SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(sql, connection.con);
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@course", course);
SqlDataReader read = command.ExecuteReader();
if (read.Read())
{
    siname = read["Name"].ToString();
    siemail = read["Email"].ToString();
}
read.Close();
```

Answer (score -1):

You may need to add a single quote on the sql statement like

```
string sql = "select * from SI where Course = '" + course + "'";
```

However, the way you have it right now is susceptible for SQL injection as well. Ideally you execute it with sql parameter.